# Crystal Report Engine RunTime Error

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, reference, runtime-error, business-objects

**Hello,**

I convert the project visual studio & the crystal reports to Version 10

but the server has the old version so i have to add the old references

IT show the report but i'm having a problem on printing and engine issue

**Crystal Report Bar Engine :**

[image: Report Bar]

**Server message :**

[image: Server Error Message]

**Local message :**

```
Server Error in '/' Application. 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

HTTP Error 404 - Not Found. 

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
Version Information: ASP.NET Development Server 10.0.0.0
```

**Tried :**

-- Re install  the Crystal Report 10 .

-- Delete all Crystal Report references and add it again .

-- Clean the Solution , remove the references and add it again .

(~ **latest result (current status):**

I realized that i have install `CRforVS_13_0_2` that have the package `CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_2.msi` and my computer is 32-bit operating system .. so i install `CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_2.msi` and it finished the installation unlike  `CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_2.msi` .. but the problem with Business Objects still there as it shown in the "Crystal Report Bar Engine " image . ~)

**Note :** If i add the new references of crystal report ,it sure work on the local but not on

the server . So i have to work with the old references.

**HELP .**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK ,

**( ~** If the server has the older version, then you have to make your `framework` &

`Crystal Reports` References compatible with the server sittings . **~ )**

So in my case i changed all of my projects framework to `framework 3.5`  and all my 
`Crystal Reports` References to version `10.5.3700.0` . And still using the 2010 Visual Studio .

**IT is working fine now . Thanks for helping guys .**

Answer (score 7):

### Analyze the problem

It's possible to analyze the problem, and find a **403 (Forbidden)** error

- using **client tools** (debug window of browser)

`GET http://someServer:20080/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js 403 (Forbidden)

GET http://someServer:20080/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/images/style.css 403 (Forbidden)`

- or **server tool** (IIS log , on WIN2003 is placed in `%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\LogFiles\W3SVC###\`).

> 2011-03-28 13:00:49 W3SVC701536 95.228.38.41 GET /aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/images/style.css - 20080 - 192.168.1.2 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0) 403 6 64 Errore!
>   2011-03-28 13:00:49 W3SVC701536 95.228.38.41 GET /aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13/js/crviewer/crv.js - 20080 - 192.168.1.2 Mozilla/5.0+(compatible;+MSIE+9.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/5.0) 403 6 64 Errore!

### Cause the problem

- In both cases i found that `crv.js` and `style.css` some files were not served;
- these files are placed by CR installer in `wwwroot\aspnet_client` folder, but for some reasons they cannot be reached;
- In my case the reason is that i create a **different website (port 20080) and aspnet_client folder is not placed inside that website**

I can see that you use different versions of software and different configurations, but **i think you have the same problem**.

### Solution

The solution is to work on IIS  this way:

- **Copy `aspnet_client` folder** from `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` folder to the **new website root folder**.

or  (this one is better)

- **Create a virtual directory** called `aspnet_client` that points to `c:\inetpub\wwwroot` **inside the new website**

Comment: I tried the solution that you gave me ... but it didn't work ..  maybe i didn't understand your meaning of "the new website root folder" .. believe me i tried  ..

Comment: Also the problem that you assumed is completely different from what i am having .

Comment: This solved my issue (I found it easiest to just copy the while folder and drop it into the web project within Visual Studio). Thanks a bunch... :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss path of report. Please check report path at loading time. Because i have already fetch same issue. So change path in publish version on server.
May be this help to you....

Comment: the report can be called and it appears on the local & also on the server .. so there is nothing wrong with the reports path ... the issue is the reports engine ..

Answer (score 0):

To avoid copying aspnet_client folder simply add in webconfig:

```
<businessObjects>
   <crystalReports>
      <crystalReportViewer>                                       
        <add key="resourceURI" value="~/localhost/aspnet_client/system_web/4_0_30319/crystalreportviewers13"/>
      </crystalReportViewer>
    </crystalReports>
</businessObjects>
```

**Note**: aspnet_client folder must be configured as an application in IIS

Answer (score 0):

[This worked after adding the section shown in the image, in the webconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqHLF.png)

```
 <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="businessObjects">
      <sectionGroup name="crystalReports">
        <section name="rptBuildProvider" type="CrystalDecisions.Shared.RptBuildProviderHandler, CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, 
                 PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, Custom=null"/>
        <section name="crystalReportViewer" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <businessObjects>
    <crystalReports>
      <rptBuildProvider>
        <add embedRptInResource="true"/>
      </rptBuildProvider>
      <crystalReportViewer>
        <add key="ResourceUri" value="/crystalreportviewers13"/>
      </crystalReportViewer>
    </crystalReports>
  </businessObjects>
```